# Веб-приложение и работа с Connection Pool

Tags: java, jdbc

Всем привет, есть веб-приложение, и класс который осуществляет соединение к БД, подскажите пожалуйста как создать в этом классе Connection Pool, и возможно ли это?

```
public class DbUtil {
    private static Connection connection = null;

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        if (connection != null)
            return connection;
        else {
            try {
                Properties prop = new Properties();
                InputStream inputStream = DbUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/db.properties");
                prop.load(inputStream);
                String driver = prop.getProperty("driver");
                String url = prop.getProperty("url");
                String user = prop.getProperty("user");
                String password = prop.getProperty("password");
                Class.forName(driver);
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return connection;
        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: Вам сюда: https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/.
Готовое решение уже.

Comment: @Tsyklop спасибо за ссылку, знать бы как это еще применить к моему случаю

Comment: Там есть примеры.  Поглядите. Создаете синглтон, передаете туда параметры. и все.

Comment: это получается в мой этот класс где конекшн создается, connection pool добавить не получится, нужно другой класс создавать?

Comment: Ответил ниже. с примером

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте библиотеку [Apache Commons DBCP](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/).

Пример:

```
public class DataSource {

    private BasicDataSource basicDataSource;

    private static DataSource ourInstance = new DataSource();

    private DataSource() {
        try {

            basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();

            basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            basicDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database");

            basicDataSource.setUsername("root");

            basicDataSource.setPassword("");

            basicDataSource.setInitialSize(10);

            basicDataSource.setMaxWaitMillis(180000);

            basicDataSource.setDefaultAutoCommit(true);

            basicDataSource.setPoolPreparedStatements(true);

            basicDataSource.setConnectionProperties("useUnicode=true;characterEncoding=utf8");

            basicDataSource.setLogAbandoned(true);
            basicDataSource.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(30);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static DataSource getInstance() {
        return ourInstance;
    }

    public BasicDataSource getDataSource() {
        return basicDataSource;
    }

    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return basicDataSource.getConnection();
    }

}
```

Задаете нужные параметры и подключаетесь к бд.

В нужном месте просто берете `Connection`: `DataSource.getInstance().getConnection()` и используете. После этого закрываете его: `connection.close()` и подключение возвращается в пул.

Comment: ругается на эту строку  `LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(DataSource.class);` и пишет: `incompatible types: Class<DataSource> cannot be converted to String`

Comment: @СергейНиконенко убрал логгеры. А что вы делаете? не знаю как вы там дальше и что делаете.

Comment: Сейчас проверю, без логгеров ошибок нет .

Comment: При открытии страницы пишет `java.sql.SQLException: Connection is null` в сервлете делаю так `public class Search extends HttpServlet {

    //private Connection connection;
    Connection connection = null; 
    public Search() throws SQLException {
        super();
        connection = DataSource.getInstance().getConnection();
        //connection = DbUtil.getConnection();
    }` и в конце когда все данные отправляю на страницу закрываю конекшн

Comment: @СергейНиконенко а зачем это делать в конструкторе? делайте в методе обработки запроса `doPost` или `doGet` или другие.